# Заслуженно — впору/впрок/даром?

Tags: лексика

Можно ли использовать один из нижеприведённых наречий в значении "заслуженно":

1. Он даром получил этот приз. Даром, что он получил эту награду;
2. Ему впору было побеждать. Владислав усиленно занимался, а потому одержал верх над соперником впору;
3. Иван готовился интенсивно к пересдаче, а потому впрок получил хорошую оценку.

Comment: Посмотрите в словарях, есть ли у данных слов значение "заслуженно". Если нет, то нельзя.

Comment: Эти слова употреблены неправильно, даже не учитывая значение "заслуженно". Просто гляньте их в словаре, чтобы понять, в чём проблема, там всё просто с употреблением.